# Segmentation Fault Issue:

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I've been searching for the location of this issue and cannot seem to find it/must be overlooking something. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#define MAX_LETTERS 26

char alphabet[MAX_LETTERS];

void initialize_alphabet(char *a) {
  char *p;
  char current_letter = 'a';
  for (p=a;p<(a+MAX_LETTERS);p++) {
    *p = current_letter++;
  }
}

void reverse_print_alpha(char *b) {
  static var = 0;
  char *p;
  var?(p=NULL):(p=b);
  var ^= 1;
  initialize_alphabet(p);
  for (p=(b+MAX_LETTERS-1);p>=b;p--) {
    printf("%c",*p);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
  int i = 0;
  while (i++<10) {
    reverse_print_alpha(alphabet);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you run the debugger and narrow down where the problem is? You need to do some debugging. This site isn't a debugging service. It's intended as a place to get an answer to a more specific question regarding code. But to show all of your code and ask, "where is my problem?" isn't a good question. NOTE: just at a quick glance, in `main` you didn't even initialize `i` before using it. I suspect you have other similar oversights. Read through your code carefully.

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot to post my use of the debugger. It shows the segmentation fault as occurring in:  *p = current_letter++;

Comment: initialize i variable.

Comment: `var?(p=NULL):(p=b);` would be far better and more idiomatic as `p = var ? NULL : b;`. However, when `p` is `NULL`... well, trace through the code yourself; I haven't a clue what you are trying to achieve in that case.

Comment: What do you think `initialize_alphabet(p)` will do if `p` is NULL? What is `p` pointing to when you do `*p = current_letter++` in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least 2 issues I see.

1) You never initialize `int i` to be `0` in the main function. That loop would be more explicit if you used a for loop instead of a while there. You would have caught the error yourself in that case.

2) You are incrementing both `p` and `*p` in your `initialize_alphabet()` function every iteration. That is, first it is running:

`*p = current_character++;` which increments both the character `p` points to and `current_character`. Second, it is running:

`p++` which moves your pointer passed the memory it was previously pointing to.

---

I don't understand what you are doing in any of these functions because variables which should be integers are characters, and vice-versa. I think you would benefit from taking a step away from each of these functions, hand-writing exactly what you think your code is doing in each of these loops, and comparing it to the actual variables being changed each loop either through the use of a debugger or a lot of print statements. Once you've found where those two diverge, you'll be able to fix all the problems yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Ah I see someone is stuck on C291 Quiz 8.

The reason this doesn't work is partially because of i, but mostly because you didn't allocate memory for alphabet and p. Both of them point to 0x0 by default, which is dedicated to the operating system. Since the mem addresses are invalid you need to allocate a DIFFERENT memory address.

Edit: Move the declaration of alphabet INSIDE of the main function.